# When is "place" used as "home"?

Tags: word-usage

Today, while chatting, I just made a sentence:

> I want you at his place at 9.

But I am not sure when to use *place* with the meaning, *home*, or *work place*? Is it correct usage? What will be the correct sentence instead?

Comment: Can you explain what your sentence is supposed to mean?  It doesn't make sense as written with the '*I want* ***me*** *at*'.  *His place* will usually always refer to his home unless context dictates otherwise.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, it was a typo, corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is when you put a possessive noun in front of *place*, it means the possessor's home.

It's usually used only conversationally and it depends on the context, though. You can put someone in *their place*, and it won't necessarily mean their home, but instead it would mean to put them back in line (assuming they were once out of order or acting innapropriate).

Answer (score 1):

*Place* is an informal way of referring to where someone lives. In more formal contexts, *home* or even some longer expression, is appropriate. *Place* is typically used when a gentleman says to a lady when suggesting a cup of hot chocolate or malted milk at the end of an evening, *Your place or mine?*